# yuicompressor for css throws error for some files

Tags: css, phpstorm, yui-compressor

i just tried using the yuicompressor for CSS. Works for most files, but for one it didnt, and gives me this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.1\jre\jre/bin/java" -jar C:/nodejs/node_modules/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar style.css -o style.min.css
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4663)
```

After these lines there are thousand errors.

I looked at another post here but it didnt fix it really. It said something about increasing the stack size(?), if thats the solution, how would i do that? google wouldnt give me any useful answere either.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase the stack size, you need passing `-Xss` option to java. Default is 512k, try increasing it, for example to `-Xss2048k`.

To do this, you either need to modify `node_modules\yuicompressor\nodejs\cli.js` accordingly, by adding `args.unshift('-Xss2048k');`:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    fs = require('fs'),
    compressor = require('./index'),
    args = process.argv.slice(2);

args.unshift(compressor.jar);
args.unshift('-jar');
args.unshift('-Xss2048k');
...
```

and then specify a path to yuicompressor binary in a Program field of your file watcher (like `C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\yuicompressor.cmd`).

Or, set up your file watcher in a different way, using java as a Program:

```
Program: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.1\jre\jre\bin\java.exe
Arguments: -Xss2048k -jar "C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yuicompressor\build\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar " $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css
```